# In graph, how can i bound the expectation of random variable representing the number of steps taken in a random work?

Tags: graph-theory

While reading a book for practicing myself, 
i have encountered following exercise. (This is not a homework or something)

> On input a graph G=(V,E), consider the connected component of vertex s, denoted G'=(V',E').
>   For any edge (u,v) in E', let $T_{u,v}$ be a random variable representing the number of steps taken in a random walk starting at u until v is first encountered.
>
> Prove that $E[T_{u,v}]\leq 2|E'|$.
>
> Hint : Consider the "frequency" with which this edge is traversed in a certain direction during an infinite random walk, and note that this frequency is independent of the identity of the edge and the direction.

could anyone give me more hints?